# Robot Framework how to call keyword with variable library name

Tags: robotframework

I have a 2 similar Remote Libraries with same keywords.

```
Library    Remote    172.18.92.194:50000    WITH NAME Client1
Library    Remote    172.18.92.194:50000    WITH NAME Client2
```

and i wish to create test case, which be run keyword from this libraries
Something like that.

```
Connect to FTP server active mode
[Arguments]    ${Client}
${Client}.ftp connect active mode     host    user    password
```

The problem is that RF is not parsing the contents of the variable in the call of keywords with the syntax library name.keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robot will not resolve variables when calling a keyword like that. What you can do, however, is use Run Keyword, like so:

```
Connect to FTP server active mode
    [Arguments]   ${Client}
    Run keyword   ${Client}.ftp connect active mode    host    user    password
```